# I am having this error,“cannot import name cilent

Tags: python

```
from dropbox.client import DropboxOAuth2FlowNoRedirect

from dropbox.client import DropboxClient
```

Comment: Is `DropboxOAuth2FlowNoRedirect` on a new line?

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
# Include the Dropbox SDK
import dropbox

# Get your app key and secret from the Dropbox developer website
app_key = 'INSERT_APP_KEY'
app_secret = 'INSERT_APP_SECRET'

flow = dropbox.client.DropboxOAuth2FlowNoRedirect(app_key, app_secret)
```

Some items cannot be imported on their own.